# how to get private IP of EC 2 dynamically and put it in /etc/hosts

Tags: terraform

I would like to create multiple EC2 instances using Terraform and write the private IP addresses of the instances to `/etc/hosts` on every instance.

Currently I am trying the following code but it's not working:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ceph-cluster" {
  count = "${var.ceph_cluster_count}"
  ami           = "${var.app_ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.small"
  key_name      = "${var.ssh_key_name}"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    "${var.vpc_ssh_sg_ids}",
    "${aws_security_group.ceph.id}",
  ]

  subnet_id                   = "${element(split(",", var.subnet_ids), count.index)}"

  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  // TODO 一時的にIAM固定
  //iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.app_instance_profile.name}"
  iam_instance_profile        = "${var.iam_role_name}"

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = "true"
    volume_size           = "30"
    volume_type           = "gp2"
  }

  connection {
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("${var.ssh_key}")}"
    agent = "false"
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "../../../scripts"
    destination = "/home/ubuntu/"
  }

  tags {
    Name = "${var.infra_name}-ceph-cluster-${count.index}"
    InfraName = "${var.infra_name}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
        "cat /etc/hosts",
        "cat ~/scripts/ceph/ceph_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys",
        "cp -arp  ~/scripts/ceph/ceph_rsa ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa",
        "chmod 700 ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa",
        "echo 'IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa' >> ~/.ssh/config",
        "echo 'User            ubuntu' >> ~/.ssh/config",
        "echo '${aws_instance.ceph-cluster.0.private_ip} node01 ceph01' >> /etc/hosts ",
        "echo '${aws_instance.ceph-cluster.1.private_ip} node02 ceph02' >> /etc/hosts "
      ]
  }

}


aws_instance.ceph-cluster. *. private_ip
```

I would like to get the result of the above command and put it in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar need for a database cluster (some sort of poor's man Consul alternative), I ended using the following Terraform file:

```
variable "cluster_member_count" {
  description = "Number of members in the cluster"
  default = "3"
}
variable "cluster_member_name_prefix" {
  description = "Prefix to use when naming cluster members"
  default = "cluster-node-"
}
variable "aws_keypair_privatekey_filepath" {
  description = "Path to SSH private key to SSH-connect to instances"
  default = "./secrets/aws.key"
}

# EC2 instances
resource "aws_instance" "cluster_member" {
  count = "${var.cluster_member_count}"
  # ...
}

# Bash command to populate /etc/hosts file on each instances
resource "null_resource" "provision_cluster_member_hosts_file" {
  count = "${var.cluster_member_count}"

  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.cluster_member.*.id)}"
  }
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = "${element(aws_instance.cluster_member.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
    user = "ec2-user"
    private_key = "${file(var.aws_keypair_privatekey_filepath)}"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      # Adds all cluster members' IP addresses to /etc/hosts (on each member)
      "echo '${join("\n", formatlist("%v", aws_instance.cluster_member.*.private_ip))}' | awk 'BEGIN{ print \"\\n\\n# Cluster members:\" }; { print $0 \" ${var.cluster_member_name_prefix}\" NR-1 }' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null",
    ]
  }
}
```

One rule is that each cluster member get named by the `cluster_member_name_prefix` Terraform variable followed by the count index (starting at 0): *cluster-node-0*, *cluster-node-1*, etc.

This will add the following lines to each "aws_instance.cluster_member" resource's `/etc/hosts` file (the same exact lines and in the same order for every member):

```
# Cluster members:
10.0.1.245 cluster-node-0
10.0.1.198 cluster-node-1
10.0.1.153 cluster-node-2
```

In my case, the `null_resource` that populates the `/etc/hosts` file was triggered by an EBS volume attachment, but a `"${join(",", aws_instance.cluster_member.*.id)}"` trigger should work just fine too.

Also, for local development, I added a `local-exec` provisioner to locally write down each IP in a `cluster_ips.txt` file:

```
resource "null_resource" "write_resource_cluster_member_ip_addresses" {
  depends_on = ["aws_instance.cluster_member"]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${join("\n", formatlist("instance=%v ; private=%v ; public=%v", aws_instance.cluster_member.*.id, aws_instance.cluster_member.*.private_ip, aws_instance.cluster_member.*.public_ip))}' | awk '{print \"node=${var.cluster_member_name_prefix}\" NR-1 \" ; \" $0}' > \"${path.module}/cluster_ips.txt\""
    # Outputs is:
    # node=cluster-node-0 ; instance=i-03b1f460318c2a1c3 ; private=10.0.1.245 ; public=35.180.50.32
    # node=cluster-node-1 ; instance=i-05606bc6be9639604 ; private=10.0.1.198 ; public=35.180.118.126
    # node=cluster-node-2 ; instance=i-0931cbf386b89ca4e ; private=10.0.1.153 ; public=35.180.50.98
  }
}
```

And, with the following shell command I can add them to my local `/etc/hosts` file:

```
awk -F'[;=]' '{ print $8 " " $2 " #" $4 }' cluster_ips.txt >> /etc/hosts
```

Example:

```
35.180.50.32 cluster-node-0 # i-03b1f460318c2a1c3
35.180.118.126 cluster-node-1 # i-05606bc6be9639604
35.180.50.98 cluster-node-2 # i-0931cbf386b89ca4e
```

Answer (score 3):

Terraform provisioners expose a [`self`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-your-own-resource) syntax for getting data about the resource being created.

If you were just interested in the instance being created's private IP address you could use `${self.private_ip}` to get at this.

Unfortunately if you need to get the IP addresses of multiple sub-resources (eg ones created by using the `count` meta attribute) then you will need to do this outside of the resource's provisioner using the [`null_resource` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html).

The resource provider docs show a good use case for this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "cluster" {
  count = 3
  ...
}

resource "null_resource" "cluster" {
  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.cluster.*.id)}"
  }

  # Bootstrap script can run on any instance of the cluster
  # So we just choose the first in this case
  connection {
    host = "${element(aws_instance.cluster.*.public_ip, 0)}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    # Bootstrap script called with private_ip of each node in the clutser
    inline = [
      "bootstrap-cluster.sh ${join(" ", aws_instance.cluster.*.private_ip)}",
    ]
  }
}
```

but in your case you probably want something like:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ceph-cluster" {
  ...
}

resource "null_resource" "ceph-cluster" {
  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers {
    cluster_instance_ids = "${join(",", aws_instance.ceph-cluster.*.id)}"
  }

  connection {
    host = "${element(aws_instance.cluster.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
        "cat /etc/hosts",
        "cat ~/scripts/ceph/ceph_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys",
        "cp -arp  ~/scripts/ceph/ceph_rsa ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa",
        "chmod 700 ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa",
        "echo 'IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/ceph_rsa' >> ~/.ssh/config",
        "echo 'User            ubuntu' >> ~/.ssh/config",
        "echo '${aws_instance.ceph-cluster.0.private_ip} node01 ceph01' >> /etc/hosts ",
        "echo '${aws_instance.ceph-cluster.1.private_ip} node02 ceph02' >> /etc/hosts "
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: >> output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 2 is TypeList) in:

you get this error..

Comment: If you're seeing an error then it might be worth creating your own question showing what you've tried and the error you get. That way it's easier for someone to be able to answer what is wrong with your specific issue.

Comment: What I meant was - your solution doesn't work as it throws an error :P

Answer (score 1):

This could be a piece of cake with Terrafrom/[Sparrowform](https://github.com/melezhik/sparrowform). No need in null_resources, with the minimum of fuss:

## Bootstrap infrastructure

```
$ terrafrom apply
```

## Prepare Sparrowform privision scenario to insert ALL nodes public ips / dns names into every node's /etc/hosts file

```
$ cat sparrowfile

#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use Sparrowform;

my @hosts = (
  "127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4",
  "::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6"
);

for tf-resources() -> $r {
  my $rd = $r[1]; # resource data
  next unless $rd<public_ip>;
  next unless $rd<public_dns>;
  next if $rd<public_ip> eq input_params('Host');
  push @hosts, $rd<public_ip> ~ ' ' ~ $rd<public_dns>;
}

file '/etc/hosts', %(
  action  => 'create',
  content => @hosts.join("\n")
);
```

## Give it a run, Sparrowform will execute scenario on every node

```
$ sparrowform --bootstrap --ssh_private_key=~/.ssh/aws.key --ssh_user=ec2-user
```

PS. disclosure - I am the tool author