# How to populate hosts file with IPs then invoke ansible playbooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform

I have 2 "aws_instance" resource modules one for master, and another for multiple worker instances. Here's the Terraform code:

```
#Create and bootstrap EC2 Kubernetes Master in us-east-1
resource "aws_instance" "kubernetes-master" {
  provider = aws.region-master
  ami = "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a" #Ubuntu 18 x64
  instance_type = var.instance-type
  key_name = aws_key_pair.master-key.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.kubernetes-sg.id]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet_1.id

  tags = {
    Name = "kubernetes_master_tf"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_main_route_table_association.set-master-default-rt-assoc
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws --profile ${var.profile} ec2 wait instance-status-ok --region ${var.region-master} --instance-ids ${self.id}
ansible-playbook --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_${self.tags.Name}' ansible_templates/kubernetes-master.yml
EOF
  }
}

#Create EC2 Kubernetes Workers in us-east-1
resource "aws_instance" "kubernetes-worker" {
  provider = aws.region-master
  count = var.workers-count
  ami = "ami-0747bdcabd34c712a" #Ubuntu 18 x64
  instance_type = var.instance-type
  key_name = aws_key_pair.master-key.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.kubernetes-sg.id]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet_1.id

  tags = {
    Name = join("_", ["kubernetes_worker_tf", count.index + 1])
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_main_route_table_association.set-master-default-rt-assoc
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
aws --profile ${var.profile} ec2 wait instance-status-ok --region ${var.region-master} --instance-ids ${self.id}
ansible-playbook --extra-vars 'passed_in_hosts=tag_Name_${self.tags.Name}' ansible_templates/kubernetes-worker.yml
EOF
  }
}
```

The idea is to invoke ansible-playbooks on them right after they're initiated. Though I stumbled upon an issue. To apply some configuration I need all these instances to include all private_ips of all instances including their own in the HOSTS file. So based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53808025/7387243) answer I ended up with this code that is supposed to populate all hosts files with all IPs:

```
resource "null_resource" "write_resource_cluster_member_ip_addresses" {
  depends_on = ["aws_instance.kubernetes-master", "aws_instance.kubernetes-worker"]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
echo ${ aws_instance.kubernetes-worker.*.private_ip } kubernetes-master # ${ aws_instance.kubernetes-master.id } >> /etc/hosts
echo '${join("\n", formatlist("%v kubernetes-worker # %v", aws_instance.kubernetes-worker.*.private_ip, aws_instance.kubernetes-worker.*.id))}' >> /etc/hosts
EOF
  }
}
```

But I now have no idea how to invoke ansible playbooks AFTER editing hosts files. The issue is also that the playbooks I am using are Master/Worker specific: "kubernetes-master.yml", "kubernetes-worker.yml", which makes it only more difficult to come up with a solution.

Comment: I don't get the link between the `/etc/hosts` file and Ansible? If you want Ansible to be able to access you EC2 instances - might they be provisioned by Terraform or not - then use the `aws_ec2` inventory source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: Possibly better yet, to not have a complexe `local-exec` in Terraform, I would 1/ build AWS instance via terraform 2/ call an ansible-playbook (or make `local-exec` do it, to be more precise in what I mean) provisioning your machine, with the `aws_ec2` inventory source, which can definitely include modifying the `/etc/hosts` files based on the variable that would be accessible from Ansible, thanks to the inventory source.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Sure, but how would I go about using dynamic inventory with this setup? How to get the list of IPs to pass to ansible?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Also, I am already using `aws_ec2` with dynamic inventories, the issue is that I have 2 separate playbooks: 1 for master, 1 for all workers. I need ALL IPs on ALL machines, though, which is the issue I am currently facing. I don't know how to reference all machines at once since they are initiated from different resources and are using different plays.

Comment: I need to update hosts file so that the further ansible plays could proceed because some of the further configuration requires this. But in any case I need to find a way to exctract the list of all IPs somehow and then write it to the hosts file. I don't know how to get all IPs from terraform to then copy them to hosts file via ansible. This is basically my question, hopefully my phrasing here is better. @β.εηοιτ.βε

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like it's quite simple. There's a resource "local_file" which does the trick:

```
resource "local_file" "instance_ip_file" {
  depends_on = [aws_instance.kubernetes-master, aws_instance.kubernetes-worker]

  content  = join("\n", concat([aws_instance.kubernetes-master.public_ip], aws_instance.kubernetes-worker.*.public_ip))
  filename = "${path.module}/instance_ip_file.txt"
}
```